# Getting CSV export to have different delimiter using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-pro, export, csv

ArcGIS Pro, using Table to Table tool, I want to export to CSV. But one of my fields is a description field that often has commas in the content. When that is exported to CSV that uses commas as delimiters, it messes everything up.

Is there a way to specify that the delimiter for the export file should be a semi colon, or something else?

Comment: If it is still an option, you could save it as a dbf, or just open a dbf of a shapefile in Excel, or other spreadsheet software. You can then save the file with whatever delimiter you wish.

Comment: I know... I was just hoping to avoid the additional manual step. And since the export concerned has over 6 million line items, Excel isn't really an option.

Comment: A custom CSV writer is under a hundred lines of Python Toolbox code. CSV itself has a way to handle strings containing commas -- quotes -- though I prefer vertical bar delimiters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a pandas dataframe from your data and use [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). A workaround, but you can choose whatever delimiter you want:

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

fc = r'C:\GIS\data\Bakgrundskartor_LMV\Vagkartan.gdb\bs_riks'

#fields = ['KKOD', KATEGORI','SRIKT'] #Either list the field names manually
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if f.type not in ('GEOMETRY','OID') and not f.name.lower().startswith('sh')] #Or like this

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields), columns=fields)
sep = '|'
df.to_csv(path_or_buf=r'C:\GIS\data\bs_riks.csv', sep=sep, header=True, index=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is an ArcGIS Pro Idea already submitted to [Add More Delimiter Options in Table Export Tools (i.e., pipe delimiter)](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/add-more-delimiter-options-in-table-export-tools-i-e-pipe/idi-p/932125):

> There are several existing tools to export a table to a flat file .txt
> or .csv, such as copy rows, table to table, or export features rows to
> ASCII. The last option at least gives you the ability to choose comma,
> space, or semicolon delimiters. The first 2 tools default to commas
> with no configuration option.

Its current Status is In Product Plan and if you vote for it then you will be helping it to be implemented sooner rather than later.